# Steps to Secure Wildfly 8

Tags: linux, centos6, wildfly-8

Steps to configure **Wild fly 8** in secure way Cent OS 6 without security loop holes.

3 Points

1. Delivering your configuration using property files
2. Securing your configuration hashing passwords
3. Securing and protecting passwords using a vault

Apart from these what else is needed to secure Wild fly 8

Answer (score 0):

Securing WildFly using HTTPS

Securing a specific application using HTTPS

Securing the WildFly console using HTTPS

Securing domain and host controllers' communication using HTTPS

Comment: http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-security/jboss-security-framework

Comment: Loop hole of Wildfly 8.1 : 
http://codesec.blogspot.in/2015/03/wildfly-8-jbossas-application-directory.html

Comment: Reference Url to Secure WildFly  

1)http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27500038/how-to-log-application-auditing-to-separate-file-on-wildfly-8

2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28568730/how-to-disable-trace-track-http-in-jboss-wildfly

3) http://blog.coffeebeans.at/archives/878

4) https://developer.jboss.org/thread/242144

5) http://blog.coffeebeans.at/archives/937